# What is the anaconda plugin for PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, anaconda

PyCharm has released a new version with an "Anaconda Plugin". I can't really tell what is this plugin and how you can use it? How is it different than a regular PyCharm where you choose an anaconda environment / package manager?

Also, the plugin homepage link is dead:

[image]

(I'm talking about the community edition)

Answer (score 9):

So far I've found only two minor differences between [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) and [PyCharm for Anaconda](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/promo/anaconda/). (I'm using the Community Editions with macOS Mojave.)

The Anaconda version

1. offers an additional item in the **Tools** menu called **Install Miniconda 3...** (apparently as part of the included "Anaconda Support" plugin, because that menu item goes away if I disable the plugin); and
2. makes Conda the default package manager (see PyCharm Community forum ["What's the difference between Pycharm and Pycharm for Anaconda?..."](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003433580-What-s-the-difference-between-Pycharm-and-Pycharm-for-Anaconda-Why-is-Pycharm-for-Anaconda-not-available-in-JetBrains-Toolbox-)).

Curiously, installing the Anaconda version of PyCharm appears to be the only way to get that plugin, because it doesn't show up in PyCharm's "Marketplace" even when I run the regular version. But if you've installed Anaconda (or Miniconda) separately you might have no use for the plugin anyway.